# Centos 7 Postfix install using MYSQL 5.7 which replaced mariadb

Tags: mysql, postfix, centos7, mariadb, mysql5.5

Sorry to disturb you, but I've a problem I can't seem to get around.

I'm trying to install Postfix on a new server which was needed to move to for more space/memory, the old server had 256MB of RAM and was quite old.

I'm pretty novice at it and have spent pretty much most of today/night trying to figure out how to get this working. The old server had `MYSQL 5.5.36` so figured there might be unexpected issues if we changed to `MariaDB` and opted to upgrade to `MYSQL 5.7.18` for the new server. We don't really have a dedicated dev ops team so I can't defer to them.

This is my error:

```
    yum install postfix
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.seas.harvard.edu
 * epel: epel.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: ftp.osuosl.org
 * updates: mirror.trouble-free.net
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.10.1-6.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64
Package 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.18-1.el5.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64
Package 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.18-1.el5.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest


# yum install postfix --skip-broken
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: linux.cc.lehigh.edu
 * epel: epel.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: ftp.osuosl.org
 * updates: mirror.solarvps.com
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.10.1-6.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64
Package 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.18-1.el5.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64
Package 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.18-1.el5.x86_64 which is already installed

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    2:postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64 from base
```

Obviously I can see that the `mariadb-libs` are obsoleted by the `mysql-community` libs, but I've completely removed? mariadb

```
yum remove mariadb-libs
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
No Match for argument: mariadb-libs
No Packages marked for removal
```

Is there anyway, I can fix this to either:

- Get Postfix installed and move on
- Maybe change to Mariadb (we have PROD data here, will this cause issues)
- Maybe downgrade to MYSQL 5.5 (don't really want to do this because going backwards isn't ideal).

Any help would be much appreciated. Users currently can't receive password reset emails from the application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to install mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.18-1.**el5** on an el7 system. You need to use packages for el7 to get the correct libmysqlclient.so.18 library.

(Answer updated, I just realized you're using the wrong package versions)

Comment: Thank you for your help.. I learned what the el means! :)